# Syslog data parsing using RE in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am dumping syslog data from my firewall and want to match connections going to a specific IP at my house. I am using this below code. The below code works as far a collecting all of the data but my IF statement never matches. I have tried without the unicode u'192.168.1.1' and without, if I just print the extracted IP's it does show up - see output below. using Python 2.7

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

## Tiny Syslog Server in Python.
##
## This is a tiny syslog server that is able to receive UDP based syslog
## entries on a specified port and save them to a file.
## That's it... it does nothing else...
## There are a few configuration parameters.

LOG_FILE = 'youlogfile2.log'
HOST, PORT = "192.168.1.2", 514

#
# NO USER SERVICEABLE PARTS BELOW HERE...
#

import logging
import SocketServer
import re
server = u'192.168.1.254'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s', datefmt='', filename=LOG_FILE, filemode='a')

class SyslogUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):

        data = bytes.decode(self.request[0].strip())
        socket = self.request[1]
        ipDST = re.compile(r'dst=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
        ipDSTExtracted = ipDST.findall(data)
        #print (ipDSTExtracted)
        if ipDSTExtracted == server:
            print (ipDSTExtracted)

        #print( "%s : " % self.client_address[0], str(data))
        logging.info(str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST,PORT), SyslogUDPHandler)
        server.serve_forever(poll_interval=0.5)
    except (IOError, SystemExit):
        raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Crtl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")
```

}

I got lots of matches in this output but im not sure if its maybe the brackets

```
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'192.168.1.254']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'192.168.1.254']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'192.168.1.209']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'192.168.1.26']
[u'8.8.8.8']
[u'8.8.8.8']
```

I have tested in idle to see and the string version and unicode version will match each other but it does not seem to work in this setup.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The square brackets indicate your output is a list; that would never match a single string; you may want to use `ipDSTExtracted[0]` instead (since `findall(...)` returns a list). Looking at your code, however, you compare to `mediasite`, which is nowhere defined, so I don't understand what you're comparing against in the first place.

Comment: I did mess the variable up it is just server and not mediasite - however using  ipDSTExtracted[0]  and if ipDSTExtracted[0] == server: without the u' it matched 1 time and then it gives an index out of range error and just continues to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findall` returns a list.  If you compare a list (the result of `findall`) with a string (I'm assuming this is the content of your `mediasite` variable) then of course the comparison will always be false.

You probably want to compare your variable against each element return by `findall`. Something like:

```
for ip in ipDST.findall(data)
    if ip == mediasite:
        print (ipDSTExtracted)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, it never matched any items.

Comment: Since you haven't shown us what `mediasite` actually contains nor provided any sample input data it's hard to validate things.  But if `ipDST.findall(data)` is returning something, you ought to be able to figure out what's going on with the rest of the loop.  If it's *not* returning anything, you have a problem with your regular expression.

Comment: there is not mediasite that was an accident i edited the code for you.

Comment: using this for ip in ipDST.findall(data):
   print ip   I get this output   which is good 192.168.1.115
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8